# hangman --can't get my loop to display correct answers

Tags: javascript

First day of school, we're supposed to make a hangman game.  I've been staring at the logic in my while loop for hours now.  I can't get my loop to say yes, the word(newWord) does contain the guess.  I always get the prompt that it is incorrect, and then all heck breaks loose.  I've tried 25 different ways.  I know it's all busted beyond repair now, but if anyone can get me going the right direction, I'd be eternally grateful.

```
  let words = ["skate", "guitar", "laugh", "party", "shirt"]

let wordValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

let newWord = words[wordValue];

let misses = 0;
let rightGuess = 0;
let wrongGuess = 0;
var answerLines = [];
for (let i = 0; i < newWord.length; i++) {
    answerLines[i] = "_";
}
    let remainingLetters = newWord.length;



    while (remainingLetters > 0 && misses < 6) {
        alert(answerLines.join(" "));
        let guess = prompt("Guess a letter, any letter!");


            for(let j = 0; j < newWord.length; j++) {
                if (newWord[j] === guess) {
                    rightGuess++
                }
                else { wrongGuess++ }
                if (rightGuess != 0) {

                    answerLines[j] = guess;
                    remainingLetters--;
                }



            else {
                misses++
                (alert("That was is incorrect.  You have " + misses + " of 6 misses."));
```

Comment: are you using Type Script ?

Comment: Yeah, although to be honest I'm not entirely sure what it is or does.

Comment: refer this to get the logic http://codepen.io/cathydutton/full/ldazc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic for processing the guess is a little off.  Try this:

```
var words = ["skate", "guitar", "laugh", "party", "shirt"]

var wordValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

var newWord = words[wordValue];

console.log("Word is: " + newWord);

var misses = 0;
var answerLines = [];

for (var i = 0; i < newWord.length; i++) {
    answerLines[i] = "_";
}

var remainingLetters = newWord.length;


while (remainingLetters > 0 && misses < 6) {
    alert(answerLines.join(" "));
    var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, any letter!");

    var matchesNone = true; //boolean to track if guess matched any letters

    for (var j = 0; j < newWord.length; j++) {

        if (newWord[j] === guess) {
            answerLines[j] = guess;
            remainingLetters--;
            matchesNone = false; //the guess matched atleast one letter
        }
    }

    if (matchesNone) { //the guess matched none of the letters
        misses ++;
        alert("That was is incorrect.  You have " + misses + " of 6 misses.");
    }
}

if(remainingLetters>0) {
    alert("You failed to guess the word: " + newWord);
}else{
    alert("You guessed the word!  It was: " + newWord);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time!  I haven't worked with booleans in this way yet.  That was exactly what I needed.  Very useful tool.  thanks again!!

Comment: your welcome, try to stick with `var` instead of `let`.  Here's the difference between the two if you're interested [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword)

Comment: I'd love to but my teacher is pretty strict about this.  He thinks var is for baby javascript and wants to teach us grown-up javascript.